# define constants in PHP

Tags: php

I am using php unit for unit testing my php code.
I have following line in the code:

```
define(SERIAL_NUM_LEN,      25);
```

When phpunit runs this line, it gives following error:

```
Use of undefined constant SERIAL_NUM_LEN - assumed 'SERIAL_NUM_LEN
```

Why is it giving this error, i am just defining the constant. Any ideas?

Comment: Because the syntax should be `define('SERIAL_NUM_LEN',      25);`, as per the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) This is php politely trying to tell you that your code is wrong, nothing to do with phpunit at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
define(SERIAL_NUM_LEN, 25);
```

to this:

```
define('SERIAL_NUM_LEN', 25);
```

With the error php is just telling you to do this.